# Can you explain Bhaktamal Chappay 28?

Tags: ramanand, srisampraday, ramanandacharya

Can you explain Sri Bhaktamal Chappay 28?

Answer (score 1):

Bhaktamal was written by Śrīmad Göswāmi NābhaDas Ji Maharaj in 1585. Bhaktmāl is the garland of 200 Bhakta Charitra which Śrī NābhaDas Ji Maharāj has write down. He was initiated in Śrī Rāmānanda Saṁpradāya & his Śrī Guru was Śrī Agar Dās swami (श्रीअग्रदास स्वामी).
[image]

रामानन्द उदार सुधानिधि अवनि कल्पतरु।
विष्णुस्वामी बोहित्थ सिन्धु संसार पार करु॥
मध्वाचारज मेघ भक्ति सर ऊसर भरिया।
निम्बादित्य आदित्य कुहर अज्ञान जु हरिया॥
जनम करम भागवत धरम संप्रदाय थापी अघट।
चौबीस प्रथम हरि बपु धरे त्यों चतुर्व्यूह कलिजुग प्रगट॥

Just as God assumed twenty-four incarnations in the first three yugas, in the same way, in Kaliyuga, the Chaturvyuh of Acharyas appeared. For example, Shri Ramanandacharya ji became the pravartak ācharya of Śrī Saṁpradāya. He was very generous, his approach was not narrow in adopting the refugees. (Jagadguru Śrīmad Rāmānandācharya ji adopted people of all castes, gender etc. he did not hesitate to adopt even Malechha, that is why the word “Udāar" (Generous) has been exclusively used for him. As Śrīmad Rāmanandacharya was HIMSELF Śrī Rām as said in scriptures,

रामानन्दः स्वयं रामः प्रादुर्भूतो महीतले ।
कलौ लोके मुनिर्जातः सर्वजीव दयाकरः ॥

Śrīmad Rāmānandacharya is Śrī Rāma himself who appeared on this earth in the form of a great Muni (sage) out of his causeless mercy and compassion on all Jivas

(-Nārad Panchrātra Vaishvānar Samhitā)

Śrīmad Göswāmi Tulsidās Ji has also used the word “Udāar" frequently with Śrī Rām in Śrīmad Rāmāyaṇam:—

एहि महँ रघुपति नाम उदारा। अति पावन पुरान श्रुति सारा।।

(Śrīmad Rāmāyaṇam 1.10.1)

अवतार उदार अपार गुनं। महि भार बिभंजन ग्यानघनं।।

(Śrīmad Rāmāyaṇam 6.111.6)

परम चतुरता श्रवन सुनि बिहँसे रामु उदार।

(Śrīmad Rāmāyaṇam 6.38)

सुनहु उदार सहज रघुनायक। सुंदर अगम सुगम बर दायक।।

(Śrīmad Rāmāyaṇam 3.42.1)

मन भावत बर मागउँ स्वामी। तुम्ह उदार उर अंतरजामी।।

(Śrīmad Rāmāyaṇam 7.84.8)

तब कि चलिहि अस गाल तुम्हारा। अस बिचारि भजु राम उदारा।।

(Śrīmad Rāmāyaṇam 6.27.7)

मैं बानर फल खात न बारा। आयसु दीन्ह न राम उदारा।।

(Śrīmad Rāmāyaṇam 6.34.4)

पुनि प्रभु कहहु राम अवतारा। बालचरित पुनि कहहु उदारा॥

(Śrīmad Rāmāyaṇam 1.110.5)

ताहि देइ गति राम उदारा। सबरी कें आश्रम पगु धारा।।

(Śrīmad Rāmāyaṇam 3.34.5)

Śrīmad Rāmānandacharya was the deep ocean of love and knowledge and was the Kalpa tree itself to fulfill the desires of the devotees on this earth. Acharya Śrī Vishnuswami, the promoter of the Rudra sect, was a ship to cross the sinking beings in the ocean of death. Shrimadhwacharyaji, the promoter of the Brahma Sampradaya, was a cloud of rain of devotion (Bhakti) to fill the hearts of people with sarovar (saras) and usar (rasa). Shree Nimbarkacharya, the promoter of the Sankadik sect, was the sun who destroyed the fog of ignorance and the lighten the devotion of knowledge. By taking birth and by performing good deeds himself, he established the sects of Vaishnava Dharma completely indestructible and strong.

Thank You For Reading